# How to configure cassandra with ruby on rails and which ORM to use?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, orm, cassandra, scalability

I am working on a telecom project in RoR and our major issue is scalability.
To start off we used MySQL and then we moved to Cassandra(Cf's with wide columns solves the scalability issue) but we are keeping the MySQL intact as our models are SQL based using ActiveRecord.

I want to wipe out MySQL completely but I'm not sure how to replace AR and how to display data on the UI.
I have looked into CQL but the way our CF's are structured I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work with Cassandra from ActiveRecord, have a look at [cequel](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/), which is an adapter built on top of [cql-rb](https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb), the Ruby driver for Cassandra (disclosure: I'm the author of cql-rb).

Answer (score 0):

There is a CQL3 Ruby driver recently created, you can have a look **[here](https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb#ruby-cql3-driver)**

I don't know whether this port of CQL3 to ruby support Active Record, it acts more like a simple data mapper but it worths having a look

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you want to work with Cassandra from ActiveRecord, is the [cassandra_migrations](https://github.com/hsgubert/cassandra_migrations) gem, which uses the [Datastax Ruby driver](https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver) for Cassandra (cql-rb is no longer maintained as mentioned on their wiki... Datastax Ruby is the official continuation of the cql-rb gem).